# dygraphs and compressed (zipped) csv

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I would like to plot seismic data with dygraph.

The is that the file data have 50 samples/second for 4 hours (720.000 samples) and the csv file is big (8 Megabytes). Is possible to compress the csv data in a compressed format (server side) and decompress with dygraph?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do the compression at the HTTP level if possible. Pretty much every web browser supports [HTTP Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).